# How to get an ARM M0+ controller to retain it's last executed instruction after reboot?

Tags: arm, reset, watchdog, samd21, cortex-m0+

I want to give my application a capability under which, in case of power off, the system retains last executed instruction and once the power is turned on again it RESUMES the program sequence.
Is there any way to get access of MicroTrace Buffer/ program counter of SAMD21 MCU, might add an RTC/WDT or any other extra circuit component that can do this job?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140430/discussion-on-question-by-pritesh-gupta-how-to-get-an-arm-m0-controller-to-reta).

Answer (score 3):

as some of the comments mentioned, continuing the program from the latest state is not going to work by just preserving the program counter. You would need to preserve the entire state of the program, including stack and global variables - at least those that are relevant for you. There is an entire branch of research looking into this, called **intermittent computing**. The challenge is to reduce the amount of these *checkpoints*, that you have to store to non-volatile memory, e.g., flash, as writing to the flash costs a lot of energy.

Recently, some microcontrollers with a non-volatile ram, called FRAM, came to the market. These preserve the state on their own, so you don't have to do anything. Once the power comes back on, the MCU will just continue, where it left off. Maybe that is an option for you?

However, to just answer your question, the Program Counter is just a register, that you can access via memory-mapped IO. For the Cortex-M0 you can see the documentation of the core registers [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0497/a/the-cortex-m0-processor/programmers-model/core-registers?lang=en). Reading and writing operations to the register will work as for every other register.

Comment: This still doesn't work because MCUs have peripheral hardware that needs to be re-initialized.

Comment: True. That is also addressed as part of the "checkpoint restore" in intermittent computing. Of course, that highly depends on the application.

Answer (score 1):

> once the power is turned on again it RESUMES the program sequence. Is there any way to get access of MicroTrace Buffer/ program counter of SAMD21 MCU

No this is nonsense, since you would need to restore the state of *all* variables in the program, essentially the whole RAM + core and hardware peripheral registers, not just the program counter or the latest trace.

In addition, the way microcontrollers work when they come out of reset, is that they restore all hardware to defaults. Which is the desired behavior, in case the MCU needs to restart due to hardware problems. Therefore all hardware peripherals and their registers need to be set again.

Additionally, external hardware might need set-up code to run as well.

> We are working on a stepper motor movement application. When power is lost and comes back, the code sequence RESETS from start. But there is already some sequences are executed earlier that were crucial for proper synchronisation. So this is why we want to go back to the last state/executed code block when device reboots. We have thought of having a Coin cell or backup power source and running the MCU in sleep mode to preserve the last state

A stepper motor is very slow compared to the time a MCU boots up. If designed correctly, your MCU should be able to run all initialization code from scratch within less than a millisecond. Once that is done, the program could look at non-volatile memory (NVM) where you could have the last program state saved, then execute the relevant part of the program from there.

The way to implement this:

- Once your program makes a state machine transit, also save the current state into NVM.
- On SAMD21 specifically, there is data flash/emulated EEPROM designed for this very purpose.
- To reduce write cycles, you would have to design an algorithm with "wear levelling", typically meaning that you erase a page of data flash, then write to the last memory location not filled up with value 0xFF and that location will also be where your current state is found after reset.
- You'll need to design some means to dodge flash erase time when the page is full, an erase may take up to 6ms during which the MCU won't be able to store the state. For example you could perhaps limit how often the program does a state change to once every 10ms.
- If that's too slow then use some expensive solution with external memories.

Comment: Needless to say, you need to hire a software/embedded engineer to do this work, not just some random engineer who have heard about program counters in some introductory programming class. It's far from rocket science for a professional software engineer to implement this... I've designed several programs like this, including an almost an identical product that used ATSAMD10 (and later switched up to D20).